# Can terraform use a variable hash or map or maps to create data entries in .tf files?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have been testing terraform (v.0.10) to provision EC2 instances, Security groups, RDS instances etc in AWS for an enterprise.

I am using a module approach so that these can be "sourced" for each of my environments:

```
apps:
  main.tf
  app.tf
  vars.tf
sec_groups:
  main.tf
  sec_group.tf
  vars.tf
:
:
```

For each of my environments (non-prod, prod) I am sourcing these modules, and storing the terraform state in a remote s3 bucket - one bucket per environment.

I am providing each environment the necessary variables like subnet_cidrs, VPC name etc etc and the environments get created: VPC have their relevant subnets, which contain the relevent EC2 instances... all good!

My challenge comes when I come to add security groups (for which I have many across the various types of EC2 instance and environments) with their respective rules.

Whilst I could create the rule base in a suitable sec_group.tf file and add the egress/ ingress rules (each with their from_port, to_port, protocol, cidr_blocks..) I wondered if the information could be generated based up a (json) hash of data?

My thinking is that this global hierarchy of data could be used to hold the rules and could be processed to gather relevant rules for each environment and apply only those relevant to the current environment which 'terraform apply' is being run against, be there 2 or 200 rules. Something like this:

```
non-prod-env:
  ssh:
    from_port: 22
    to_port: 22
    protocol: "tcp"
    cidr_blocks:
      - 10.1.1.1
      - 10.2.2.2
    :
    :
  smtp:
    from_port: 25
    to_port: 25
    protocol: "tcp"
    cidr_blocks:
      - 100.1.1.1
      - 100.2.2.2
   :
   :
prod-env:
  ssh:
    from_port: 22
    to_port: 22
    protocol: "tcp"
    cidr_blocks:
      - 11.1.1.1
      - 11.2.2.2
    :
    :
```

Having read about the various types of vars (string, list, map) I'm not sure if what I am asking is even possible but it would allow a centralised (global) source of data that all environments could pull from.

I'd interested to know if anyone has considered / investigated this approach previously or if there is a much simpler approach that I might be missing.

Any thoughts or comments would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I thought I should explain more behind this question - the reasoning for wanting to consider the use of a hash (someway, some how) is similar to the way you might use hiera in puppet: to have a system of general key-value pairs that could be overridden lower down the hash. A merge would allow a single source of data minimising the use of variable duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn't support nested maps yet ([terraform#2114](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2114)) but you might be able to read from your global JSON file using an [External Data Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html).

Completely an option here, but I've come to determine that logical operations overstep what HCL was designed to do and that more complex orchestrations should instead put into a custom provider. An HCL plan should be explicit in what it's doing and not so much deriving that from external resources. Here's how I tackled ACL and security group rules:

ACL:

Where the variable `network_ssh_access` is a list of allowed cidr blocks for this VPC

```
variable network_ssh_access {
  type    = "list"
  default = []
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "main" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "network_ssh_access" {
  count          = "${length(var.network_ssh_access)}"
  network_acl_id = "${aws_network_acl.main.id}"
  rule_number    = "${200 + count.index}"
  egress         = false
  protocol       = "tcp"
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = "${element(var.network_ssh_access, count.index)}"
  from_port      = 22
  to_port        = 22
}
```

Security Group:
Where the variable `appname_ssh_access` is a list of allowed cidr blocks for the app called "appname"

```
variable appname_ssh_access {
  type    = "list"
  default = []
}

resource "aws_security_group" "appname" {
  name        = "appname"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_all" {
  count           = "${length(var.appname_ssh_access)}"
  type            = "ingress"
  from_port       = 22
  to_port         = 22
  protocol        = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks     = "${element(var.network_ssh_access, count.index)}"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.appname.id}"
}
```

You would then replicate this model for the remaining ports and protocols (mail, http, https, etc).